# How do I specify HTTP auth headers when using rdflib?

Tags: python, semantic-web, rdflib

The [docs for rdflib](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_parsing.html) show this example of loading data from a remote source

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse("http://bigasterisk.com/foaf.rdf")
len(g)
# prints 42
```

I'm trying to do this with a source that requires an auth header. How do I tell rdflib to use add a custom header to it's HTTP calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [no way](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/74c85939fd433b5b318aa5c81d25ca1f80989938/rdflib/parser.py#L79-L110) to add extra headers without resorting to fragile hacks. `Graph.parse` accepts more than URLs, though, so you can use a library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make the request:

```
import requests
from rdflib import Graph

response = requests.get('http://bigasterisk.com/foaf.rdf', auth=('user', 'pass'))
response.raise_for_status()  # raise an error on unsuccessful status codes

g = Graph()
g.parse(data=response.text)
```

Comment: thanks, i was hoping rdflib could support it because my ultimate goal is to use a linked data fragments API (http://linkeddatafragments.org/software/) so that I can put a sparql query into rdflib which would then translate it into the appropriate API calls to fetch triples. Here's an example lib, https://github.com/pchampin/hydra-py